# Nginx redirect url with parameters

Tags: nginx, redirection, slash-arguments

I searched on so many threads without any luck, maybe you can help me.

I try to redirect this link https://www.example.com/page/5/?s=gluten to https://www.example.com/gluten_specificarticle

I tried to use map solution but it does not work

```
map $arg_s $mypage {
    gluten /specificlink;
}
```

There is 2 variables in the link : '5' for page and '?s=gluten' for the search argument.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

The `$request_uri` variable contains the entire URI including the query string. You will need to use an `if` block to test the condition.

For just one redirection, you could use:

```
if ($request_uri = "/page/5/?s=gluten") { 
    return 301 /gluten_specificarticle; 
}
```

If you have a number of redirections, use a `map`:

```
map $request_uri $redirect {
    /page/5/?s=gluten    /gluten_specificarticle; 
}
server {
    ...
    if ($redirect) {
        return 301 $redirect;
    }
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: This is great thank you very much Richard ;-)

Comment: However using the map function, i have an error and can't reload nginx.

map $request_uri $redirect {
    /page/5/?s=gluten   /xxx/maladies/intolerance-et-sensibilite-au-gluten/;
    /page/3/?s=gluten   /xxx/maladies/intolerance-et-sensibilite-au-gluten/;
    /page/2/?s=gluten   /xxx/maladies/intolerance-et-sensibilite-au-gluten/;
    /page/4/?s=gluten   /xxx/maladies/intolerance-et-sensibilite-au-gluten/;
}
server {
...
    if ($redirect) {
        return 301 $redirect;
    }
...
}

Comment: I have one last question ;-) 

What if the url contain a space in it. I read that you must use a quote so i tried like this

if ($request_uri = "'/page/5/?s=Vitamine D'") { 
    return 301 /xxx/vitamines/vitamine-d/; 
}

Space between vitamine and D

But it doesn't work

Thanks

Comment: In my example, it was already within double quotes. However, the URI in `$request_uri` will probably be encoded, so spaces may be replaced by `+` or `%20`.

Comment: For the `map` problem - the `map` statement goes outside your `server` block. Use `nginx -t` to test the configuration and view the syntax error.

Comment: I don't have enough privilege to open the error.log unfortunately

It mention nothing for my case in the console